# network monitoring software

Tags: network-monitoring

Hello friends can anyone suggest me a Net Monitor for Employees tat allows you to see screens of  computers connected to the network. This way you can observe what your employees are doing!   Additionally, you have the ability to take control of a remote computer by controlling the mouse and keyboard. You can record remote computers screens even when you are not monitoring them. When your employees need instructions, you can show them your desktop. To increase your efficiency the console now include several tolls that can be executed on all or just selected remote computers. When you need attention you can send a message to employees and/or lock the remote computer.  Communication uses encryption.   Application works through Internet, LAN, WLAN or VPN. Agent can be remotely installed.

i am runnin a traing institute with 30 Pcs which uses windows Xp and i am lookin for commercial software..

Comment: i am goin to use it within my lan network..

Answer (score 2):

Seem like a puzzle of regular vnc software should do the job (recording comes separate, you may need r-vnc too), but vnc tends to be slow outside of LAN.

Comment: i am goin to use it within my lan network..so plz suggest any software name which follows all the above mentioned scenarios

Comment: I don't thing there is a single piece of software that does just that. Are you interested in free or commercial soft? Give us some details about workstations - at least the os.

Comment: i am runnin a traing institute with 30 Pcs which uses windows Xp and i am lookin for commercial software,